# Faster alternative to find() in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

I'm trying to write (an efficient) MATLAB code that does the following:

I have ~100,000 2-D data-points, and I have pairs of intervals. The first interval doesn't change (in this example between 0 and 1), and the second interval keeps changing.
I want to get the instances/data-points that have:

1) x-coordinate values within the first interval (0,1)
2) y-coordinate values within the second (changing interval)

```
% firstCol is a ~100,000 rows, one column array; x-coordinate
% secondCol is also a ~100,000 rows, one column array; y-coordinate

% boundaries of my first interval
%
maxOfMyFirstInterval = 1;
minOfMyFirstInterval = 0;

% allIntervalsMax is a ~10,000 rows, one column, of maximum values
% allIntervalsMin is a ~10,000 rows, one column, of minimum values
% 
% The above two columns contain the changing pairs, so the first pair would be
% (allIntervalsMin(1), allIntervalsMax(1))
%

% pre-allocate array that will hold number of data-points that satisfy 
% my condition
%
numberOfInstances = zeros(length(allIntervalsMax),1);

tic

% This will get the instances that satisfy my first condition,
% x-coordinate between 0 and 1
%
a_first = find((firstCol <= maxOfMyFirstInterval) & ...
    (firstCol >= minOfMyFirstInterval));

% Loop through the list of second intervals
%
for jx = 1:length(allIntervalsMax)

    a_second = find((secondCol <= allIntervalsMax(jx)) & ...
        (secondCol >= allIntervalsMin(jx)));

    a_both = intersect(a_first, a_second);

    numberOfInstances(jx) = length(a_both);
end

toc
```

The time it takes to do that is ~29 seconds, I was wondering if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would probably speed it up if you didn't bother with find and intersect.  So

```
a_first = (firstCol <= maxOfMyFirstInterval) & ...
    (firstCol >= minOfMyFirstInterval);

% Loop through the list of second intervals
%
for jx = 1:length(allIntervalsMax)

    a_second = (secondCol <= allIntervalsMax(jx)) & ...
        (secondCol >= allIntervalsMin(jx));

    a_both = a_first & a_second;

    numberOfInstances(jx) = sum(a_both);
end
```

Comment: Replacing the `find` made a big difference, the `intersect` not so much. Many thanks.